# Is it possible to see total listening time in the current month in Pandora One?

Tags: pandora

I'd like to know how many hours I listen to Pandora each month.  I am currently paying for Pandora One, and I want to know if I am getting close to, or shooting over 40 hours each month.

Is there a way to view that?  I've already looked in my profile.

Comment: To my mind, not having to hear commercials is enough to make it worth $3/month.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if there is a way with a paid account, but with a free account, I know you can click the "account" link once you've signed in, and it will show you how many free hours you have remaining. There may be something similar for Pandora One users. Just click "account" at the top of the page and see if there's any info there.

Comment: This is a good tip for free users of Pandora, but there doesn't seem to be a similar feature in Pandora One.

Comment: Bummer dude.  You'd think they could keep the hour counter there for paid users too.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an Xbox One you can see "amount listened" per station for your top 8, beyond that I don't have a clue.

Answer (score 0):

If you go onto offline mode with a paid account it will tell you how many hours you listened to your top 4 stations